# Change font size only on Desktop for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: fonts

I'm working in 20.04LTS and trying to change the font size of only the text on Desktop. I'm following instructions given for 18.04 in Question 1075561.
In 'org/gnome/desktop/interface/...' I find 'monospace-font-name', 'font-name', 'doc-font-name' but not the 'desktop-font' that is shown for 18.04 in the above question.
How should the instructions for 18.04 be modified for the 20.04 case?

Comment: I got it: /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor